# Expected value of product of non independent Bernoulli random variables (correlations are known)

Tags: correlation, expected-value, joint-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I've asked a question about getting the joint probability distribution for $N$ Bernoulli random variables, given the expected value for each one ($E[X_i]=p_i)$ and it's correlations ($\rho_{12},\rho_{13},\dots$). Someone kindly directed me to [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X9090084U), and it's been really helpful, but I still can't figure one last point out:

Given that I know the correlation matrix for the $N$ Bernoulli random variables: How can I get the expected value for the product of all of them:
$$
E\left[\prod_{j=1}^N X_j \right]=?
$$

For two Bernoulli random variables, I know that expected value is:
$$
E\left[X_1·X_2\right]=\sigma_{12}+p_1·p_2
$$ where $\sigma_{12}$ is the covariance of $X_1,X_2$ and $p_j=E[X_j]$. However, when working with three random variables, I can't find a way. My gut tells me that it can be a function of the covariances, but I don't know for sure.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordinarily, **bivariate relationships do not determine multivariate ones,** so we ought to expect that you *cannot* compute this expectation in terms of just the first two moments.  The following describes a method to produce loads of counterexamples and exhibits an explicit one for four correlated Bernoulli variables.

---

Generally, consider $k$ Bernoulli variables $X_i, i=1,\ldots, k$.  Arranging the $2^k$ possible values of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k)$ in rows produces a $2^k \times k$ matrix with columns I will call $x_1, \ldots, x_k$.  Let the corresponding probabilities of those $2^k$ $k$-tuples be given by the column vector $p=(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{2^k})$.  Then the expectations of the $X_i$ are computed in the usual way as a sum of values times probabilities; *viz.,*

$$\mathbb{E}(X_i) = p^\prime \cdot x_i.$$

Similarly, the second (non-central) moments are found for $i\ne j$ as

$$\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) = p^\prime \cdot (x_i x_j).$$

The adjunction of two vectors within parentheses denotes their term-by-term product (which is another vector of the same length).  Of course when $i=j$, $(x_ix_j) = (x_ix_i) = x_i$ implies that the second moments $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_i)$ are already determined.

Because $p$ represents a probability distribution, it must be the case that

$$p \ge 0$$

(meaning all components of $p$ are non-negative) and

$$p^\prime \cdot \mathbf{1} = 1$$

(where $\mathbf{1}$ is a $2^k$-vector of ones).

We can collect all the foregoing information by forming a $2^k \times (1 + k + \binom{k}{2})$ matrix $\mathbb{X}$ whose columns are $\mathbf{1}$, the $x_i$, and the $(x_ix_j)$ for $1 \le i \lt j \le k$.  Corresponding to these columns are the numbers $1$, $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$, and $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j)$.  Putting these numbers into a vector $\mu$ gives the *linear* relationships

$$p^\prime \mathbb{X} = \mu^\prime.$$

The problem of finding such a vector $p$ subject to the *linear* constraints $p \ge 0$ is the first step of linear programming: the solutions are the *feasible* ones.  In general either there is no solution or, when there is, there will be an entire manifold of them of dimension at least $2^k - (1 + k + \binom{k}{2})$.  **When $k\ge 3$, we can therefore expect there to be infinitely many distributions on $(X_1,\ldots, X_k)$ that reproduce the specified moment vector $\mu$.**  Now the expectation $\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2\cdots X_k)$ is simply the probability of $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$.  So if we can find two of them that differ on the outcome $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$, we will have a counterexample.

I am unable to construct a counterexample for $k=3$, but they are abundant for $k=4$.  For example, suppose all the $X_i$ are Bernoulli$(1/2)$ variables and $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) = 3/14$ for $i\ne j$. (If you prefer, $\rho_{ij} = 6/7$.) Arrange the $2^k=16$ values in the usual binary order from $(0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1), \ldots, (1,1,1,1)$.  Then (for example) the distributions

$$p^{(1)} = (1,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,0,2,2,0,2,0,0,1)/14$$

and

$$p^{(2)} = (1,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)/14$$

reproduce all moments through order $2$ but give different expectations for the product: $1/14$ for $p^{(1)}$ and $0$ for $p^{(2)}$.

Here is the array $\mathbb{X}$ adjoined with the two probability distributions, shown as a table:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
  & 1 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_1x_2 & x_1x_3 & x_2x_3 & x_1x_4 & x_2x_4 & x_3x_4 & p^{(1)} & p^{(2)} \\
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{14} & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{14} \\
  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{14} & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

---

**The best you can do with the information given is to find a range for the expectation.**  Since the feasible solutions are a closed convex set, the possible values of $\mathbb{E}(X_1\cdots X_k)$ will be a closed interval (possibly an empty one if you specified mathematically impossible correlations or expectations).  Find its endpoints by first maximizing $p_{2^k}$ and then minimizing it using any linear programming algorithm.